# can't overload operator+ on 2 classes c++ eclipse

Tags: c++, operators, copy-constructor, listiterator

I'm trying to overload operator + on 2 Movies, and for some reason it always gets stuck  when I try to get the code of them, a method which works for other classes so it probably has to do with the overloading.
I want to add a few movies together, and gather them all into a new Movie.
I found the problem was with operator =, not +, it gets stuck.. here is the code:
here is the main class trying to overload a few movies:

```
void MovieIndustry::addMoviesTogether() {
 Movie final,g;
                //moviesToAdd is a list of Movies.
   for (std::list<Movie>::iterator it2=moviesToAdd.begin(); it2 !=    
   moviesToAdd.end(); ++it2) lookfor movie
                {       
                        g =  final + (*it2);
                        final = g;
                }
   movies.push_back(final);
}
```

here are the relevant methods from Movie.cpp:

```
Movie& Movie:: operator+ (const Movie& other) {

Movie toReturn,toCheck;
   // I left its code empty because the problem was with operator =
return toReturn;

}     

 Movie::Movie() {

m_classifier = NULL;
workersInMovie.empty();
genresOfMovie.empty();
numOfWorkers=0;
numOfGenres=0;

// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

Movie& Movie:: operator= (const Movie& other) {

cout << "inside ======" <<endl; //prints this one
Worker* toAdd = NULL;
Genre* addGenre;
code = other.getCode();    //loses it here
cout <<"finihed ==== "<< endl;  // it never gets to this line
return *this;
}

Movie::Movie(const Movie& toCopy) {

  cout << "inside copy" << endl;
 *this=toCopy;

 }
```

I really cant detect the problem, but i found its rather in = than in the + method, so maybe it has something to do with the addMoviesTogether method.
HELP..?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a reference to a local value.

```
Movie& Movie:: operator+ (const Movie& other) {
 // ^^^   returning a reference.

    Movie toReturn,toCheck;
   // ^^^^^^^^^^^^   this is a local object. This will
   //                be destroyed when the function exits
   //                so your reference will point at an object that
   //                has been destroyed.

    return toReturn;
}
```

For `operator+` where you construct a new value you should return by value.

```
Movie Movie:: operator+ (const Movie& other)
```

Technically this will cause a copy to be made. But this is not as bad as it seems. First the C++ compiler has very good optimization for values returned (`NRVO` and `RVO`). Secondly with C++11 we introduced the concept of Movement. This is the classic case were an object is moved (rather than copied). This is supposed to be optimally efficient.

But alternatively you can implent `operator+=` which combines the two above statements.

```
 Movie& Movie:: operator+= (const Movie& other) {
 {
      // Add other to *this;
      return *this;
 }
```

Here we can return by reference. Because we return a reference to the current object. Now change your code in the loop.

```
            {       
                    // Old code
                    // g =  final + (*it2);
                    // final = g;

                    // New Code
                    final += (*it2);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Movie& Movie:: operator+ (const Movie& other)` you are returning reference to the local object `Movie toReturn`. You should not return reference to local object, which is allocated on stack of function, outside of function. As function exits `toReturn` destructor will be called and the reference you returned will point to the destructed object.

Correct `operator+` declaration is `Movie Movie:: operator+ (const Movie& other)`. Other code will remain same.